# NOTE or WARNING from package check when README.md includes images

Tags: r, r-markdown, pandoc

I have a package with a `README.Rmd` that I pass to `rmarkdown::render()` 
producing `README.md` and a directory `README_files`, which contains images in `README.md`. This looks like the tree below.

`README_files` is [not a standard package directory](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Package-subdirectories), so if it isn't in `.Rbuildignore`, checking the package with `R CMD check` shows a note:

`* checking top-level files ...
NOTE Non-standard file/directory found at top level:   README_files`

But including the directory in `.Rbuildignore` leads to a warning, if and only if checking the package `--as-cran`. IIUC Pandoc tries to generate HTML from `README.md`, but the images are unavailable, in the ignored `README_files` directory.

```
Conversion of ‘README.md’ failed:
pandoc: Could not fetch README_files/unnamed-chunk-14-1.png
README_files/unnamed-chunk-14-1.png: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
```

Is there any way to get a clean check `--as-cran` here?

`├── README_files
│   └── figure-markdown_github
│       ├── unnamed-chunk-14-1.png
│       ├── unnamed-chunk-15-1.png
│       ├── unnamed-chunk-16-1.png
│       ├── unnamed-chunk-26-1.png
│       └── unnamed-chunk-27-1.png
├── README.md
├── README.Rmd`

Comment: It seems the standard is to just put those images in the top directory instead, see e.g. [`ggplot2`](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2) or [`ggraph`](https://github.com/thomasp85/ggraph).

Comment: Oh, I assumed pngs in the top directory would also generate a NOTE. I'll try it.

Comment:  I don't see how e.g. ggplot2 is [avoiding](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/master/cran-comments.md) a note or warning. I get a note when I [put pngs in the top-level directory](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2), and a warning when I [add them to .Rbuildignore](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/master/.Rbuildignore).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The current preferred solution (at least as used by `ggplot2`) is to store the images in `man/figures/`. So in the `README.Rmd` file, include something like the following setup chunk.

````
```{r, echo = FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(
  collapse = TRUE,
  comment = "#>",
  fig.path = "man/figures/README-"
)
```
````

That keeps the images tucked away in a place that won't generate cran check errors, but they are still part of the package. So you don't have to store them elsewhere or use calls to `png::readPNG`.

Comment: I believe this is the best answer, but only the third option is relevant to this question (fig.path = ...).

Answer (score 3):

There are a few options. Update: I think Rob Hyndman's solution is now better than the things I list here.

1. Store the image online somewhere, and include the URL in the README.
2. As @Axeman noted, you can follow the ggplot2 approach of storing the images at the top level, and mentioning them in `.Rbuildignore`.
3. You can store them in `inst/image`, and use `png::readPNG(system.file("image/yourpic.png", package = "yourpkg"))` to read it. Then show it in the README using a plot.

Comment: Thanks. (1) works well for me here and (3) could be a good option. Oddly  I can't get (2) to work, although apparently it does for ggplot. It's the same issue as when they're in a folder; I get `NOTE Non-standard file/directory found at top level: ...` unless they're in `.Rbuildignore`, in which case I get the file-not-found warning from Pandoc.

Comment: I don't think this issue is truly solved.  (1) Would work, but then it's not truly "packaged" -- others can only read the README.md when they have internet connection.   (2)  I don't think this works because if I share the .tar.gz of my package, and someone untars it and installs, README.md won't have images.    (3)  This requires manually changing things after knitting and won't be reproducible if I make a change to README.rmd.

Comment: in addition, readPNG will dump a load of odd html, and not add an html img tag. There may be a knitr chunk option to overcome this, but without more data, I'm afraid I don't see any of the options above working.

Answer (score 2):

I followed http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/release.html. same error when putting them in top level and add to .Rbuildignore.

As Richie suggested, after adding images to inst/image, and refer to as `![](inst/image/README-unnamed-chunk-1-1.png)`