# Non-standard file/directory found at top level: 'README.Rmd' persists even after implementing suggested solutions

Tags: r, knitr, devtools, r-package

I am working on a package and running `R CMD CHECK` on it using `devtools::check()` produces the following `NOTE`:

```
> checking top-level files ... NOTE
  Non-standard file/directory found at top level:
    'README.Rmd'
```

A variant of this question has been raised before ([NOTE or WARNING from package check when README.md includes images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44113759/note-or-warning-from-package-check-when-readme-md-includes-images)), but that solution provided therein hasn't worked for me.

Here is my `.Rbuildignore` file. As has been suggested, I have included `^README-.*\.png$`:

```
^.*\.Rproj$
^\.Rproj\.user$
^CONDUCT\.md$
^\.travis\.yml$
^README-.*\.png$
^cran-comments\.md$
```

Additionally, my `README.Rmd` document has the following chunk, which saves all figures in `/man/figures/`

```
{r, echo = FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(
  collapse = TRUE,
  comment = "#>",
  fig.path = "man/figures/README-"
)
```

If you need more details about the `.Rmd` file, it's here:
https://github.com/IndrajeetPatil/ggstatsplot/blob/master/README.Rmd

Given that it's better to get rid of all possible `NOTES` to successfully pass CRAN's `R CMD CHECK`, how can I avoid this particular `NOTE`?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

To exclude the file `README.Rmd` from the tarball created by R, add

```
^README.Rmd
```

to the file `.Rbuildignore` you already have.  "Writing R Extensions" has more, should you need it.